# react-redux action creator not available on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, plaid

I am trying to use react-plaid-link to integrate plaid in to my app.  Everything works fine until I execute the handleOnSuccess callback.  I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTransferSource' of undefined

For some reason my action creators, exported out of '../../actions' aren't available when I call handleOnSuccess

This is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import PlaidLink from 'react-plaid-link';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

const plaidPublicKey = process.env.REACT_APP_PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY;

class PlaidAuthComponent extends Component {

  handleOnSuccess(token, metadata) {
    // send token to client server
    this.props.createTransferSource(metadata);  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PlaidLink
          publicKey={`${plaidPublicKey}`}
          product="auth"
          env="sandbox"
          clientName="plaidname"
          onSuccess={this.handleOnSuccess}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions )(PlaidAuthComponent);
```

from my index.js file in my actions folder

```
export * from './transfer_actions';
```

my transfer_actions.js file

```
export const createTransferSource = (values, callback) => {
  return function (dispatch){

  axios({
    method : 'POST',
    url: `xxx/transfer_source.json`, 
    data: { values } 
  })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({ 
        type: CREATE_TRANSFER_SOURCE,
        payload: response
      });
    })
    .then(() => callback())
    .catch( error => {
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_TRANSFER_SOURCE_ERROR,
      payload: error.response
    });
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: Your error says you tried to call `this.handleCreateTransferSource` - where is this call in your code? Is that a typo, and is the error actually referring to the call `this.createTransferSource` in your `handleOnSuccess` function?

Comment: good catch.  was hacking my way through and copied over the wrong error message.  updated now

Comment: `this.props.createTransferSource` instead of `this.createTransferSource`, and you were right Shubham.

Comment: updated with new code and error message.  got a bit crossed up as I tried to work through this

Comment: i added more detail on how I get createTransferSource to the component.  I export transfer_actions out of my index.js file.  In my transfer_actions is where I define the action creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `this` otherwise you would lose it in your component.

You could do this in several ways:

**Method One:**
Using arrow function

```
handleOnSuccess = (token, metadata) => {
  this.props.createTransferSource(metadata);
}
```

**Method Two:**
Binding in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.handleOnSuccess = this.handleOnSuccess.bind(this); 
}
```

**Method Three:**
Binding directly where `handleOnSuccess` was referenced.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PlaidLink
          publicKey={`${plaidPublicKey}`}
          product="auth"
          env="sandbox"
          clientName="plaidname"
          onSuccess={this.handleOnSuccess.bind(this)}
          />
      </div>
   );
}
```

**Method Four:**
Invoking `handleOnSuccess` reference with an arrow function

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PlaidLink
          publicKey={`${plaidPublicKey}`}
          product="auth"
          env="sandbox"
          clientName="plaidname"
          onSuccess={() => this.handleOnSuccess}
          />
      </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this here:  https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/328

I added the following code

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleOnSuccess = this.handleOnSuccess.bind(this); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write `handleOnSuccess` this way :

```
handleOnSuccess = (token, metadata) => {
  this.props.createTransferSource(metadata);
}
```

So that you preserve the `this` context and not require a constructor for the binding.